# SCSS addclass in nextjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

Im working in a nextjs project and using scss module procedure for styling

One sample component directory looks like this
SampleComponent -> index.tsx and SampleComponent.module.scss

code in  SampleComponent.module.scss

```
.box{
    // some css (say set1)
    &.disabled{
        // some other css (say set2)
    }
}
```

in index.tsx

```
import styles from './SampleComponent.module.scss'


<div className={styles.box}></div>
```

How can i add disabled class here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using css modules how do I define more than one style name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949469/using-css-modules-how-do-i-define-more-than-one-style-name)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add both 'box' and 'disabled' classes to your div. If so, you can use template literals for this purpose as

```
<div className={`${styles.box} ${styles.disabled}`}></div>
```

Or you can add both classes to make a single string as

```
let classes =  styles.box + ' ' + styles.disabled
```

and then

```
<div className={classes}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use classnames package for it
https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

```
<div className={classNames(styles.box, styles.disabled)}></div>
```

Or you also can use it like this:

```
<div className={`${styles.box} ${styles.disabled}`}></div>
```