# next.js: How to work with className (CSS components modules)

Tags: javascript, css, next.js

I am discovering Next.JS and I am struggling with working with the syntax resulting with working with components css modules inside html code in a .js file.

A tutorial I watch explained that:

```
<a className="btn"</a>
```

would become the following with css module classes.

```
<a className={classes.btn}</a>
```

However I am confused on how to deal with things like:

```
<a className='navbar-logo fab fa-typo3' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>Home</a>
```

or

```
<i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
```

I can't find a way to learn how to correctly write the className content with classes nowhere. Help would be kindly accepted!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using css modules how do I define more than one style name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949469/using-css-modules-how-do-i-define-more-than-one-style-name)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the CSS module, try using template string.

```
<a className={`${classes.navbar-logo} ${classes.fab} ${classes.fa-typo3}`} onClick={closeMobileMenu}>Home</a>
```

Comment: `classes.navbar-logo`, `classes.fa-typo3` won't work. One needs to use array-like notation to access keys in such cases, like `classes['navbar-logo']`.